# Is there any way to use enum inside my component's HTML in angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Is there any way to use enum inside HTML template in angular 2 & above?

eg: I have an enum in my component:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'test',
 templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
})
export class TestComponent{
 constructor(){}
 ngOnInit(){}
}

export enum Tab{
 tab1='tab 1',
 tab2='tab 2',
 tab3='tab 3'
}
```

And inside the HTML template, when I use `Tab.tab1` returns an error, but it's working in `component.ts`
How can I use these `Tab` enum inside my component's HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it very easily. You need to assign a variable to your enum like this:

```
public TAB = Tab;
```

Then in your html template you can simply do something like that:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="anotherVariable === TAB.tab1>
  foo
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

The template has access only to the public properties of the component. So to allow `Tab` enum usage inside components template you should do the following:

```js
@Component({
 selector: 'test',
 templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
})
export class TestComponent{
 Tab = Tab;

 constructor(){}
 ngOnInit(){}
}

export enum Tab{
 tab1='tab 1',
 tab2='tab 2',
 tab3='tab 3'
}
```